# Get only one Jsonobject reponse while there are two match data?

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I wrote the PHP code below to get multiple JSON objects from my database:

```
<?php

    $connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","","Fubon");
    $dateCheckSQLCommand = $connection->prepare("select * from clockindata where Month(date)= 11 ");
    $dateCheckSQLCommand -> execute();
    $result = $dateCheckSQLCommand->get_result();

    $rowOfDate = $result->fetch_assoc();

    echo json_encode($rowOfDate);
```

I expect to get two JSON objects when I run the PHP file like below because I have two month 11 data matching in My MySQL:

```
[{"account":"Fu","ssid":"Fu","date":"2019-11-14 00:00:00"},{"account":"Fu","ssid":"Fu","date":"2019-11-21 00:00:00"}]
```

But I only get one JSON object like below:

```
{"account":"Fu","ssid":"Fu","date":"2019-11-14 00:00:00"}
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: You're only fetching one row. You either need to loop over `fetch_assoc` or use `fetch_all`

Comment: Tip: You may want to use shorter names for your statement handles, like `$stmt` is traditional in PHP. This in contrast to the very verbose `$dateCheckSQLCommand` where SQL doesn't really have "commands" anyway, but "statements" instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fetch each row in your result. You're only calling [`fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) once in your code. You need to either loop until `fetch_assoc()` returns false, or use [`fetch_all()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) (which is supported [only by the mysqlnd driver](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-all-mysqlnd).)

```
$connection = new mysqli("localhost","root","","Fubon");
$dateCheckSQLCommand = $connection->prepare("select * from clockindata where Month(date)= 11 ");
$dateCheckSQLCommand -> execute();
$result = $dateCheckSQLCommand->get_result();

/*** either this ****/
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rowOfDate[] = $row;
}

/*** or this, if it's supported ***/
$rowOfDate = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($rowOfDate);
```

The best solution, though, will involve changing the database API you're using. Mysqli is not very user friendly, and was written as a low-level one-to-one mapping of MySQL's C API. Even using [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), which is PHP's other built-in database API, will make your code much easier to work with. Here's how that would look, including a [parameterized query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for safety:

```
$month = 11;
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Fubon", "root", "of course you have a password");
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM clockindata WHERE MONTH(`date`) = ?");
$stmt->execute([$month]);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// if your script is outputting JSON, set the MIME type appropriately
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($data);
```

Especially when you're using parameters in your query (which you already are, of course, right?) PDO becomes far easier to use than Mysqli.

Comment: MySQLi also has `fetch_all()`

Comment: Right I'd forgotten about that. IIRC there were some gotchas but I'll update the answer.

Comment: The gotcha is that by default the numerical array is provided. In PDO by default I think it is both.

Comment: I was thinking about how it's only supported by mysqlnd driver. Not sure how much of a concern that is any more though. Just been using Laravel/Eloquent for years now.

Comment: If someone doesn't have the mysqlnd driver then it is their fault and they will have others problems e.g. missing `get_result()`